# Cannot convert value of type 'MKCoordinateRegion' to expected argument type 'Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>'

Tags: swiftui, mkcoordinateregion

I am new to SwiftUI and I'm trying to pass in some coordinates from an object I have inside a `NavigationStack`

I feel my approach is correct but the error suggests it needs a two way binding property which I don't have in this instance.

I tried setting a variable called `var region` and then passing that to the `Map` but I don't think I can use code in the middle of a `View` ?

What am I doing wrong?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var chargingSessions: [ChargingSession] = [ChargingSession(id: 1, Name: "John", Kwh: 2.003, Price: 3.04, StartDate: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(-10000), Latitude: 59.9139, Longitude: 10.7522),
                                               ChargingSession(id: 2, Name: "Dave", Kwh: 4.003, Price: 6.04, StartDate: Date.now.addingTimeInterval(-1000000),Latitude: 59.9239, Longitude: 10.7622)]
    
    
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()

    let regionSize = 500.0
  
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        TabView {
            
            Text("Home Screen")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home",systemImage: "house.fill")
                }
            
            
            NavigationStack {
                List(chargingSessions) { chargingSession in
                    
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "ev.charger.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.031, green: 0.251, blue: 0.302, opacity: 1.0))
                            .imageScale(.large)
                        
                            .padding(.trailing, 5.0)
                        VStack{
                            NavigationLink(chargingSession.StartDate.formatted(.relative(presentation:.named)), value:chargingSession).fontWeight(.bold)
                            
                            Text(chargingSession.Price.formatted()+"kr")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            
                            Text(chargingSession.Kwh.formatted()+"kWh")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("Charging Sessions")

                .navigationDestination(for: ChargingSession.self) { chargingSession in
               
                    Map(coordinateRegion: MKCoordinateRegion(center: chargingSession.Coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionSize, longitudinalMeters: regionSize))
  
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bolt.car.fill")
                Text("Sessions")
            }
            
            Text("Profile Screen")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Profile",systemImage: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                }
        }
        .tint(Color(red: 0.031, green: 0.251, blue: 0.302))
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a Binding, Map requires a two-way variable instead of just an initial value. Try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials first. Some might suggest using .constant but it is generally bad practice to use it outside of previews.